# How can I open device's directory using Ionic Framework, or ng-cordova?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to open the device's directory, using Cordova in a Ionic Framework, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [cordova-plugin-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file). This implements a File API allowing read/write access to files residing on the device. Examples are available in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file).

Install it using : `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file`